# Split file by XML tags

Tags: java, xml, split, tags

I'm an amateur at Java coding and I'm stuck in an assignment. I've written most of the code except the fundamental part, and I'm drawing a blank on how to go about doing it. I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction on how it's done.

I have made a class called `Splitter`. Its job is to read in an XML file and split it into smaller files based on specific XML `start` and `end` tags, while each smaller file must also be smaller than a given `maxfilesize`.

Also, older versions of the file must be put into an archive folder with a time stamp. I've mostly got it. Except that I'm not sure how to make this split by the `start` and `end` tags. I have got a `getXML` method that reads everything between those tags; but from there, when I call it into the split method, I'm not really sure what to do with it.

Anyone have any input they could share to steer me in the right direction?

```
public class Splitter {

  public static void split(String directory, String fileName, 
        String transactionTag, int fileSize) throws IOException{
    String startTag = "<"+ transactionTag + ">";
    String endTag = "</"+ transactionTag + ">";
    File f = new File(directory + fileName);
    File output = new File (directory + "Output/" + fileName);
    BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
    Splitter sp = new Splitter();
    int fileCount = 0;
    int len;
    int maxFileSize = fileSize;
    byte[] buf = new byte[maxFileSize]; 
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_hh_mm_ss");
    Date curDate = new Date();
    String strDate = sdf.format(curDate);
    String fileTime = strDate;
    while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
        fileCount++;
        try{
            File afile =new File(directory + "Output\\" + fileName + "." + fileCount);
            if(afile.exists()){
                if(afile.renameTo(new File(directory + "Output\\Archive\\" + fileName + "." + fileCount + "-" + fileTime))){
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Files failed to be archived. ");
                }
            }else{
                System.out.println("This file does not exist.");
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(output + "." + fileCount));
        String newInput = new String(buf,0,len); // newInput is a String no greater in length than whatever bytes or chars
        String value = sp.getXML(newInput, transactionTag);

        //This part is incomplete.
        //Do something with value to make this class split the file by XML tags.
        //Also make sure any left over code before the first start tag and last end tag are also put into smaller files.

        int start = value.indexOf(startTag);
        int end = value.lastIndexOf(endTag);

        out.write(buf,0,len);
        out.close();
    }
    in.close();
  }
  public String getXML(String content, String tagName){
    String startTag = "<"+ tagName + ">";
    String endTag = "</"+ tagName + ">";
    int startposition = content.indexOf(startTag);
    int endposition = content.indexOf(endTag, startposition);
    if (startposition == -1)return "";
    startposition += startTag.length(); 
    if(endposition == -1) return "";
    return content.substring(startposition, endposition);
  }
  public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException{
    int num = 100;
    int kb = num * 1024;
    Splitter split = new Splitter();
    split("C:/SplitUp/", "fileSplit.xml", "blah1", kb);
    System.out.println("Program ran");
  }
}
```

Comment: IIUC your single input file (`fileSplit.xml`) has multiple `start` and `end` tags, and you will to split the content between each pair of `start` and `end` tags into separate individual files, right?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right. As it is, I have this code working to where it splits the file by the fileSize, but I also need it to split by those start and end tags. I have that getXML method which sees the content between the start and end tag, and I know I need to call that in to the split method and do some kind of loop to make that split everything, but I'm not sure how to go about doing that. I also need to file the "leftovers", meaning put the stuff before the first start tag and the stuff after the last end tag into their own files as well. I would be grateful of any shred of insight.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, I am assuming that your `fileSplit.xml` looks something like this:

```
<header>
  <!-- Some XML metadata -->
<header>
<start>
  <!-- Some XML data -->
</start>
<start>
  <!-- Some XML data -->
</start>
<start>
  <!-- Some XML data -->
</start>
<start>
  <!-- Some XML data -->
</start>
<footer>
  <!-- Some XML metadata -->
<footer>
```

where each `<start>`, `<header>`, `<footer>` and their corresponding closing tags are on their own line.

You can simplify your codes by using:

1. [`java.nio.files.readAllLines(Path path, Charset cs)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset)) to read your `C:/SplitUp/fileSplit.xml`
2. [`java.io.FileWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html) to write to all your sub-files.

Essentially (for Java 7+) you can do something like,

```
// read the entire fileSplit.xml into an array of string
List<String> fileContent = files.readAllLines(Paths.get("C:/SplitUp/fileSplit.xml"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

// iterate through the array to split the file content into sub-files
String subFileContent = "";
for(String line : fileContent){
  if(line.compareToIgnoreCase("<start>") != 0 || line.compareToIgnoreCase("<footer>") != 0) { // keep reading if this line isn't a <start> nor a <footer>
    subFileContent += line;
  }
  else { // if this line is a <start> or a <footer>, write all the content thus-far into a new sub-file
    // sub-files names taken from your codes above. Make sure they are unique!
    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(directory + "Output\\" + fileName + "." + fileCount++);

    // this will write up to only maxFileSize number of characters.
    // how do you want to handle spillover?
    fileWriter.write(subFileContent, 0, maxFileSize);

    // reset subFileContent
    subFileContent = new String(line);
  }
}
```

In terms of satisfying the requirement of

> ...each smaller file must also be smaller than a given maxfilesize

You can change the last `else` to an `else if` to force the `subFileContent` to be written out when its `length()` exceeded `maxFileSize`, and make sure the remainders are written out to the second sub-file. But I'll say get the first part of splitting the content into sub-files working first, before dealing with the second requirement.